# android: blocking SMS when other SMS app are installed

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

i am building an app for blocking SMS , its working fine but when i install any other SMS blocking app , message first goes to that app and then comes to my app if that app does not block it.  i want to access message in my app first.i have set android:priority="1000" and i have tried  999 as well but it didn't work for me

```
        android:name="pk.wisesolutions.smsmanager.activity.IncomingMessage"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Post code what you have tried. In sms broadcast receiver you will receive msg.Store it in your app db and then delete from message inbox programatically.

Comment: @yuvaツ when other app is installed , i could not received a messages, if that message is blocked by that other app, i have added my manifest code

Answer (score 0):

Pre KitKat 4.4 that can happen, you can update receiver priority to be max possible integer (you most probably chose your priority based on docs but you can go higher) but again if another app is doing the same thing and calls *abortBroadcast* and it was installed before yours, your app will not be notified.

```
<intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
```

Post KitKat 4.4, you do not have to worry about that if you are using *android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED*

Comment: @GunnerFan it didn't work for me and i am still waiting for the right answer